# How to treat "impossible values" in sums of choose operators?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, proof

I am trying to prove that $2^n = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \binom{n}{k}$ using $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$.

(Exercise v-a in Appendix 1 of Jim Pitman's Probability.)

I prove it by induction and in the final step I end up with terms $\sum_{z=-1}^{z=p-1} \binom{p-1}{z}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{k=p} \binom{p-1}{k}$.

Since the choose operator is undefined for those terms I trucate the series and end up with: $\sum_{z=0}^{z=p-1} \binom{p-1}{z}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{k=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k}$, each of which by inductive hypothesis is equvalent to $2^{p-1}$.

Am I allowed to make this sort of trucations? Is there a more elegant way to deal with "impossible values"?

Edit. Added my attempt at the proof below. The step I am not sure about is in bold.

$n=0$ :

$\sum_{k=0}^{k=0} \binom{0}{k} = \frac{0!}{0!0!}= 1 = 2^0$

$n=p-1$ assume:

$2^{p-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{k=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k}$

$n=p$ :

$\sum_{k=0}^{k=p} \binom{p}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{k=p} \binom{p-1}{k-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{k=p} \binom{p-1}{k} = $

**by setting** $z=k-1$ **and because** $\binom{p-1}{p}$ **is undefined**

(**$z=-1$ and $k=p$ "dissapear"**)

$=\sum_{z=0}^{z=p-1} \binom{p-1}{z} + \sum_{k=0}^{k=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k} = $

by inductive hypothesis

$= 2^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} = 2^{p}$ (Q.E.D.)

Edit2. Neat solution to the final step (based on Charles Eliot's comment) is:

$n=p$ :

$\sum_{k=0}^{k=p} \binom{p}{k} = 1+1+\sum_{k=1}^{k=p-1} \binom{p}{k} = 1+1+\sum_{k=1}^{k=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{k=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k} = 1+\sum_{k-1=0}^{k-1=p-2} \binom{p-1}{k-1} + 1+\sum_{k=1}^{k=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k} = \sum_{k-1=0}^{k-1=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{k=p-1} \binom{p-1}{k}= 2^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} = 2^{p}$ (Q.E.D.)

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It might be better to show us some of your intermediate steps in the proof in case you have gone astray somewhere.

Comment: The "choose operator" $\binom{n}{k}$, usually known as a *binomial coefficient*, is [defined for *all* complex numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html) $n$ and $k$ except when $n$ is a negative integer and $k$ is not an integer. I don't believe your formulas include any such undefined values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the generating function you're using

$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$

is not applicable when $k = 0$ or $k = n$. However, you already know that

$\binom{n}{0} = 1$ and $\binom{n}{n} = 1$

always, so when you're doing the proof by induction just immediately covert all terms with $k = 0$ or $k = n$ to $1$ as soon as they come up, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When something is undefined, you have the luxury of defining it. In this example, your formula is:

$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}.$$

In fact, this formula will still hold if $k=1$ and $k=n$ if you define $\binom{a}{0}$ and $\binom{a}{a+1}=0$ (this is actually a common definition for binomial coefficients). Now you don't have to worry about indices (see comments for details).

Comment: Your assertion is not generally true: often the "undefined" objects, to be meaningful, *must* satisfy the same kinds of relationships expected of the defined objects.  To see what can go wrong, try "defining" $\binom{-1}{k}$ for non-negative integral $k$ to be some arbitrary values and then compare your definitions to the values those expressions *must* have in order to be called binomial coefficients.

Comment: @whuber: $\binom{-1}{k}=-1$. Also see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351695/negative-binomial-coefficients

Maybe I've miscommunicated my point. I'm not redefining classical binomial coefficients. In fact I don't even care what binomial coefficients are here. Rather, I am defining certain boundary cases of *Pascal's Rule*. This is a common technique in generating function theory where it's much easier to define boundary issues, rather then reindex sums to avoid them. So in this case, I would think your "rules" are precisely that binomial coefficients satisfy Pascal's Rule.

Comment: @whuber: In other words as long as OP's proof does not use other explicit properties of binomial coefficients, such as $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, then such a definition above is perfectly fine.